# How do I set a variable as value in a pointer array

Tags: c

I am working with C and I was wondering if there is a way to do this.

```
int main ()
{

  int *p = {5,6};


int a = *(p + 1);


 printf("%d", a);

 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: What is `int *p = {5,6};`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int *p = (int[]){5,6};
    int a = *(p + 1);

    printf("%d", a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh, this is a more direct solution, I didn't know of this kind of syntax, never had to use such things until now.

Comment: Thank you, this code seems to work and is most efficient for what I'm doing.

Comment: @iharob it's Compound literal since C99.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{

    int  x[] = {5,6};
    int *p   = x;
    int  a   = *(p + 1);

    printf("%d", a);

    return 0;
}
```

the `{5, 6}` is for array initialization, you can't initialize a pointer as if it was an array, but you can have a pointer to an array, and you can initalize an initialized array with `{5, 6}`, so define the array, define a pointer that points to the array, and then `a = *(p + 1);` will work.